# Installing Python modules

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to install the pyperclip module for Python 3.6 on Windows (32 bit). I have looked at various documentations (Python documentation, pypi.python.org and online courses) and they all said the same thing.

1) Install and update pip

I downloaded get-pip.py from python.org and it ran immediately, so pip should be updated.

2) Use the command *python -m pip install SomePackage*

Okay here is where I'm having issues. Everywhere says to run this in the command line, or doesn't specify a place to run it.

I ran this in the command prompt: *python -m pip install pyperclip*. But I got the error message "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

If I run it in Python 3.6, it says pip is an invalid syntax. Running it in IDLE gives me the same message.

I have no idea where else to run it. I have the pyperclip module in my python folder. It looks like a really simple problem, but I have been stuck on this for ages!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the location of the python.exe to your $PATH variable. This depends on your installation location. In my case it is C:\Anaconda3. The default is C:\Python as far as I know.

To edit your path variable you can do the following thing. Go to your Control Panel then search for system. You should see something like: "Edit the system environment variables". Click on this and then click on environment variables in the panel that opened. There you have a list of system variables. You should now look for the Path variable. Now click edit and add the Python path at the end. Make sure that you added a semicolon before adding the path to not mess with your previous configuration.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be obtuse, but I still can't get it to work. Could you give me an example of the command you enter?

Comment: Edited my answer.